# Lag in multiindex time series panel data on R

Tags: r, regression, multi-index, panel-data

I have a dataset with hundreds of rows structured like this

```
User    Date        Value1  Value2
A       2012-01-01  4       3
A       2012-01-02  5       7
A       2012-01-03  6       1
A       2012-01-04  7       4
B       2012-01-01  2       4
B       2012-01-02  3       2
B       2012-01-03  4       9
B       2012-01-04  5       3
```

As the panel data has two indices (User=k, Date=t), I struggle to run a regression on R where the dependent variable (Value 1) is lagged only on the time index. the regression should be performed as follows:

Value1(k,t+1) ~ Value2(k,t) 
or
Value1(k,t) ~ Value2(k,t-1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: group_by with lag  ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post the dput() of the example dataframe so we can give you a reproductible example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For every user, you can do:

```
> df <- data.frame(User = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
+                  Date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by = "day"), 2),
+                  Value1 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5),
+                  Value2 = c(3, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 9, 3))
>   
> df_A <- df[df$User == "A", c("Value1", "Value2")]
> ts_A <- ts(df_A, start = c(2012, 1, 1), frequency = 365)
> ts_A <- ts.intersect(ts_A, lag(ts_A, -1))
> colnames(ts_A) <- c("Value1", "Value2", "Value1_t_1", "Value2_t_1")
> 
> lm(Value1 ~ Value2_t_1, ts_A)

Call:
lm(formula = Value1 ~ Value2_t_1, data = ts_A)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   Value2_t_1  
     6.3929      -0.1071  

>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the dplyr package, you may notice in the code below I explicitly reference the lag function from dplyr as opposed to base R (stats). This is because the lag function from dplyr does not require a time series input.

I would also note that the two formulas you list may produce different regression results as you will be running them over different sets of data i.e.

Value1(k,t+1) ~ Value2(k,t) : run on the time period of 1-01-2012 to 1-03-2012

Value1(k,t) ~ Value2(k,t-1) : run on the time period of 1-02-2012 to 1-04-2012

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(User = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
             Date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by = "day"), 2),
             Value1 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             Value2 = c(3, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 9, 3))

df2 <- df %>% arrange(User,Date) %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(lag_v2 = dplyr::lag(Value2), 
         lead_v1 = dplyr::lead(Value1))



df3<-df2[!is.na(df2$lag_v2),]
df4<-df2[!is.na(df2$lead_v1),]

summary(lm(Value1~lag_v2,data=df3))
summary(lm(lead_v1~Value2,data=df4))
```